# API - Undocumented? - Hide part of the snippet (not all of it)

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, api

I'm looking at the code inside `snippet-javascript....js` files, I can see I can hide as in the UI checkbox the snippet, sending hide var. but what I want is (if possible) to select to hide for example the css, but not the html. so in `<!-- begin snippet: js` on each `<!-- language: lang-...` is there anyway to hide selected parts of the snippet? couldn't find it in the source code... maybe is not possible, but maybe there is a non documented way... so I thought I will ask. the idea is that maybe you want to post a snippet but only show the html or the JS of it. (if you open the snippet editor you see everything)

edit: I'm asking more about the API itself, is it possible to do it now with a non documented way? (it would be great to have it in the sites too, but interested anyway if I can use it right now/asap)

note: I'm working on a power editor for Stack Overflow

Thanks

Comment: Yes, possible duplicate of that, but my question is about a feature request, but also maybe it is already implemented but not released in the sites... anyway I could use it using the api, so is the same concept but also asking about the internal API

Comment: This is a duplicate.  The API can do less (generally) than the live site can.   So, such a feature will never get implemented in the API until the live site has it first. ... Especially since the API is just setting markdown in this case -- which any site user could see and copy, if it worked.

Comment: is just a tag, maybe there is a special param that hides it.. (?)

Comment: No, it is markdown, and always will be.  And, **if the duplicate feature request gets implemented, you will automatically be able to use it from the API.**

Comment: jej... with "tag" I meant an html tag... `<!-- lang...`

Comment: The "tag" you are referencing is just an HTML comment!  It's *effect* in an SE post is part of SE's *markdown* syntax.

Comment: I know... but I'm just asking if there is any part of that specific html tag that can cause it to hide... just that...

Comment: No.  Hence the duplicate feature request.